# OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex Bug Garbage Collector (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, garbage-collection, opengl-es-2.0

I'm drawing a simple triangle using opengl-es 2.0 on android (tests on nexus4).

On continuous draw mode i'm rotating this triangle using a rotation matrix and setting the uMVPMatrix inside the vertex shader.

**The Problem**

I'm new to open gl but this is quite basic and works good, but after around 30 seconds the garbage collector kicks in:

```
05-05 19:12:23.359  26333-26357/com.x.app V/Renderer﹕ Surface created
05-05 19:12:23.369  26333-26357/com.x.app V/Renderer﹕ Changed surface width:1196 height: 768
05-05 19:12:59.307  26333-26357/com.x.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 436K, 5% free 9121K/9588K, paused 64ms, total 65ms
05-05 19:13:48.910  26333-26357/com.x.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 522K, 6% free 9105K/9664K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
05-05 19:14:39.144  26333-26357/com.x.app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 6% free 9104K/9664K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
```

After the second GC Round there is another Rectangle on the screen, sometimes a Line.
[image: Vertex bug after second garbage collector run]
[Another image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cs0I.png)

After one or two garbage collector runs, it's gone again and this happens over and over again.

I guess there's some binding between the shader code and java that i did horribly wrong.

**My Code**

My triangle draw method:

```
 public void draw(float[] mMVPMatrix) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    int mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
```

The vertex buffer (Triangle constructor):

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            triangleCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
    vertexCount=triangleCoords.length;
```

Comment: Your shader is actually completely irrelevant to this question. More than likely what is actually going on has to do with your vertex pointer setup. In particular, if you create a pointer to a buffer that is not *"direct"* then the JVM will make life miserable for OpenGL. Are you using VBOs?

Comment: Thx, yes. I edited my post. The vertex Buffer looks fine to me (maybe im wrong), but i wonder if i should/could use a buffer for the mvp matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use DDMS *'Start Tracking'* and *'Get Allocations'* buttons to track memory allocations. It will show you all your allocations. More information here: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#alloc

Looking at your code, I'd strongly recommend you to call `GLES20.glGetUniformLocation` only once right after you've compiled shader and store these values in `int` variables. Finding uniforms/attributes by string identifier quite is time-consuming and my wild guess is that it also allocates some memory (not much but you do it *each* frame). Don't do that on each draw call.

Other than that, this question is not relevant to OpenGL ES, it is a common garbage collection issue which you can easily track in DDMS.

Comment: Exactly. Allocating buffers/textures before drawing each frame will also produce this kind of strange OpenGL drawing behavior.